# Can this angular directive be Improved?

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

I've create a floating label directive, which gets the existing placeholder's value and puts it into a div element which serves as a floating label. The placeholder attribute is then deleted and the label tag is hidden. The directive works fine, but I am concerned about how it manipulates the DOM. I wonder if there is a better (cleaner) way to:
1) manage the template for the floating label div element:

```
  var template = '<div class="floating-label">{{ placeholder }}</div>';

  //append floating label template
  $element.after($compile(template)($scope));
```

2) find the label tag by the for attribute (the one that is associated with the input):

```
document.querySelector('label[for="' +  $scope.id +  '"]').style.display = 'none';
```

It should be noted that jqLite is used. (no jQuery)

The [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/RyJWJYZ3KoA12316DyfS?p=preview) with the directive

Comment: why don't you use transclusion?

Comment: Also, this kind of question is more suitable on the [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site, I believe, since there is not actually a problem you are trying to fix.

Comment: What would transclusion improve?

Comment: I think @Claies brought up transclusion because you are manually compiling a template.

Comment: yes, I mentioned transclusion based on the `$compile` statement, before I had a chance to really review the plunker in depth.   after taking a look at it, I quickly realized I was a bit off in that thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks pretty good, just a few comments:

- I would drop the isolated scope and just use the `attrs` parameter; eliminates the need for the $compile service.
- Do not require ngModel
- Consider deleting the  node. (I could go either way on this)
- [reference my changes](http://plnkr.co/edit/9BCcMcszTaodUZcAvcnK?p=preview)

Comment: Accepted it as it has valid points. I am not deleting the label tag since it is an accessibility feature as described here: http://www.coolfields.co.uk/2011/04/accessible-forms-should-every-input-have-a-label/

Comment: Oh yeah good point.  I am always getting in trouble with 503.